# Xubunu keeps freezing

Tags: freeze, xubuntu

I have cloned a classroom of Xubuntu 22.04 computers in my lab using clonezilla, and they keep randomly freezing.  I have all of the updates.  Symptoms are the second screen usually flashes to black, and then the machine is frozen, only to be reset by a hard reboot. Where do I go to start to troubleshoot and fix my dilemma?  Xubuntu 22.04 worked fine on these systems last year.

Comment: Look at the logs just before the last crash: `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`. If the logs are unhelpful, suspect power/overheating. Please [edit] your Question and explain how you "cloned a classroom of Xubuntu 22.04 computers" in more detail.

Comment: Thank you will do